# PAM unable to dlopen(pam_systemd.so) after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, do-release-upgrade, pam

I had an old web server that needed an upgrade from 14.04 to 18.04. I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04, then from 16.04 to 18.04 one after the other. It is behind a proxy, and on that proxy, I see `connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream`.

On the backend server, in `/var/log/auth.log`, I see:

```
PAM unable to dlopen(pam_unix.so): /lib/security/pam_unix.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
PAM adding faulty module: pam_unix.so
PAM unable to dlopen(pam_ecryptfs.so): /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1: symbol __close_nocancel, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
PAM adding faulty module: pam_ecryptfs.so
PAM unable to dlopen(pam_systemd.so): /lib/security/pam_systemd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
PAM adding faulty module: pam_systemd.so
```

I have another server that has the same purpose as a backend behind a proxy, and it is a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04. The `/lib/security` directory is not even present on that server, but it is present on the problem server.

Contents of `/lib` directory on working server:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 74656 Nov  9  2017 klibc-wBFLvVtxy4xJqEadIBJMa78iJz8.so
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Feb 12  2018 terminfo
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 14416 Apr 18  2018 libhandle.so.1.0.3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    18 Apr 18  2018 libhandle.so.1 -> libhandle.so.1.0.3
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Feb 14  2019 lsb
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 14  2019 init
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 14  2019 console-setup
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 14  2019 netplan
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 14  2019 open-iscsi
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 14  2019 modules-load.d
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 14  2019 apparmor
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Feb 14  2019 recovery-mode
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 14  2019 hdparm
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 14  2019 ufw
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Feb 14  2019 cryptsetup
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 14  2019 ebtables
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Aug 17  2020 resolvconf
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    21 Aug 17  2020 cpp -> /etc/alternatives/cpp
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 12288 Sep 16  2020 systemd
drwxr-xr-x 84 root root 20480 Dec 11 06:48 firmware
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Dec 11 06:48 crda
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Feb 10 06:15 udev
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 16384 Feb 19 06:35 x86_64-linux-gnu
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root  4096 Apr 16 06:30 modules
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 17 06:51 modprobe.d
```

Contents of `/lib` on fautly server:

```
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Mar  1  2011 terminfo
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    21 Jan 23  2012 cpp -> /etc/alternatives/cpp
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    20 Jan  8  2014 libxtables.so.10 -> libxtables.so.10.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 47712 Jan  8  2014 libxtables.so.10.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 70952 Nov 14  2017 klibc-k3La8MUnuzHQ0_kG8hokcGAC0PA.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    25 Dec  7 10:38 ld-linux.so.2 -> i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Apr 12 16:48 cryptsetup
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Apr 12 16:50 lsb
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Apr 12 16:51 plymouth
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 12 16:51 ifupdown
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Apr 12 16:51 recovery-mode
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 20480 Apr 12 16:52 xtables
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 12 16:59 security
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 12 17:02 resolvconf
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 12 17:02 apparmor
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 12 17:02 hdparm
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Apr 12 17:03 crda
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 12 17:06 modules-load.d
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 13 08:13 ufw
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root  4096 Apr 22 16:18 modules
drwxr-xr-x 87 root root 36864 Apr 22 16:20 firmware
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 22 16:55 init
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 23 09:56 modprobe.d
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root  4096 Apr 23 09:56 systemd
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Apr 23 09:57 udev
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 12288 Apr 23 10:15 i386-linux-gnu
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 20480 Apr 23 11:55 x86_64-linux-gnu
```

The only file that is present in `/lib/security` on the faulty server is:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18744 Jul 13  2016 pam_ecryptfs.so`

I cannot figure out:

1. Why the /lib/security directory is not present on the working server
2. If I even need it on the faulty one
3. What is pointing to the missing `.so` files that can possibly be changed.

Help would be grealy appreciated. Otherwise, I'm going to have to do a fresh install.

Comment: Yeah, I went from 14.04 to 16.04, then from 16.04 to 18.04. I'll note that.

Comment: And this is not off topic. It is running 18.04 after two upgrades.